# Maximum possible value of a positive integer $n$, such that for any choice of seven distinct elements from ${1, 2, .., n},$ there will exist

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, functions

What is the maximum possible value of a positive integer $n$, such that for any choice of seven distinct elements from ${1, 2, ..., n},$ there will exist two numbers $x$  &  $y$ satisfying $1 < x/y \leq 2$

What seems unclear to me are the following points,

A) Is $2y$ supposed to be $\leq$ n ?

B) Is there some standard approach to find the maximum possible value?

Moreover, usually, I try to take a small set to try out the given conditions. In this case, is it possible to take a smaller set and use it to draw conclusions for the larger set?

The answer is $2^7 - 2$

Comment: The answer to $(a)$ is no, there is no assertion that  $2y \leq n$ must be true. For (B) , yes, there is a standard approach. "Be greedy" is your mantra. Imagine you choose a number $x$ . Automatically, every number between (and including) $\frac{x}{2}$  and $2x$ cannot be included in your choice. You now have to find ways to allow as little elimination a possible. Be greedy, and try to pick numbers so that you can fit as many in as possible, using this mantra. Now see if things work out. Also think about why powers of $2$ get involved, as they probably would.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon This question had options. When I saw $2^7 - 2$, I guessed it was right. It seemed correct to assume that considering all subsets of some 7 elements, the following conditions would hold true. After seeing the answer, I can't understand why 2 needs to be subtracted. Moreover, your greedy algorithm is exactly how I began but could you mention some more steps? I could not arrive close to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I might see the question lacking context a little, so I will ask you for permission to edit your comment into the question, since it's a good question. It comes down to this :I want to include $1$ in the set and build upward and see where it leads me. So I try to do this : if $1$ is in that set, then $2$ can't be, so we force $3$ in , now $4,5,6$ can't be , so we force $7$ in etc. and the pattern is that we get the set of powers of two, minus $1$. So we reach $2^7-1=127$, our set has the elements $\{2^1-1,...,2^7-1\}$, which is an issue. So we know $2^7-1$ doesn't work.

Comment: So for $2^7-1$, by being greedy, we obtained a set of $7$ numbers such that you cannot find two numbers in that $x,y$ such that $1 < \frac xy \leq 2$. Therefore, we kind of guess, because being greedy can be optimal, that $2^7-2$, which is the next smallest number, works. It does , because you can look at the intervals between the numbers $2^1-1, 2^2-1,...,2^7-1$ which are six intervals, and with the pigeonhole principle prove that there are at least two numbers in the same interval, which would satisfy the criteria.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Oh Yes! That made it clear.

Comment: If the hint works, then you can self-answer the question if you'd like confirmation from me, since I didn't mention all the details and writing a complete answer helps everybody! If it doesn't work and you'd like me to expand, then I can edit your attempt (or whatever you tried of the greedy algorithm) into the question, and then answer the question. Either will do nicely. I can also mention stuff about being greedy (although corporates would do a better job than me!) as a technique.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Could you please add how $2^t - 1$ becomes $2^7 - 2$ in the answer just posted?

Comment: Sure, you have given me permission to edit the answer, hence I will do so.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon You can always edit. Permission not required.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! Of course, I have upvoted all content here. It's just courtesy. There have been a few incidents where posters haven't liked edits and have expressed it, so I suppose it's good to ask!

Comment: I edited your answer to complete it on your request. I didn't want to write a separate answer since you took the effort to write your own. Thanks once again for doing so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with smaller values is the key here. Elimination can be done once a pattern is seen.

On the basis of the conditions given ($1 < x/y \leq 2$), try taking some numbers. Notice that, as mentioned in the comments, Choosing $1$ restricts the entry of $2\times1$
Thereafter, choosing $3$, restricts the entry of all numbers $\leq 2 \times 3$

Finally we are left with $7$. This clearly points to the fact/pattern that we get a number that is of the form $2^t-1$. Continuing the trend, we easily observe that the set $\{1,3,7,15,...,127 = 2^7-1\}$ is a set consisting of seven elements, *no* two $x,y$ of which satisfy the criteria that $1 < \frac{x}{y} \leq 2$.  Therefore, we know that the answer to the question is at most $127$.

We guess that it is $126$. Indeed, here is a proof. Divide $126$ into the following parts : $S_1 =\{1,2\}$, $S_2 = \{3,4,5,6\}$, $S_3 = \{7,8,...,14\}$, ..., $S_6 = \{63,64,...,126\}$. Now, if you pick any two elements $x,y$ from the same $S_i$, then either $1 < \frac{x}{y} \leq 2$ or $1 < \frac {y}{x} \leq 2$. This can be easily checked.

By the pigeonhole principle, if we pick $7$ elements between $1$ and $126$, two of them must be in the same $S_i$, and hence we are done.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon Thanks for the hint and the edit. Well explained.

Comment: We did it together! This question will stand in my memory for very long.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes!

Comment: Great! Finally, to complete the proceedings , you can accept this answer when you are allowed to do so. Of course you can wait for others, but this is also very nice.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I tried. Two days later.

Comment: Sure, of course we can wait for it!